# FMDB and UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, fmdb

We have a database of many many rows in sqlite3. We are utilizing the FMDB Wrapper for SQLite3 to show data in a UITableView. It is preferred that we do not use Pagination as this doent feel very normal for an iPhone/iPad application. We were hoping that if we MUST do so we could do so in the form of 400 or so records.

What is the best way to do this? Is there any way to call the database on

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

?

Even if we do a "More Records…" table cell, what will happen once they reach a huge number? Will we have to do 2-way pagination?

What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I do, with a similar setup that has thousands of rows for the UITableView.

I have an array (actually a C++ stl vector) where each item in the array maps to a row in the UITableView.  The array populated with the sqlite record ID's for the items I want to display.  The memory taken by the array is 4 bytes per row.

cellForRowAtIndexPath looks up the record ID in the array, then queries from sqlite the fields I need for the cell.  It's plenty fast since SQLite indexes the record ID column.

Mine is actually a bit more complicated since I have TableView sections, as well as a TableView index.  But not overly more complicated.

Comment: I use a similar approach but fetch in blocks of 10 or 20 with [db executeQuery:@"select x from items where id in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" withArgumentsInArray:ids]. With statement caching turned on this is fast enough to smoothly scroll a 10,000 row table view on a first gen iPod touch.

Comment: Where can I find source code example of such a project? Thanks.